# Forbid extending class from implementing a constructor

Tags: typescript, class, oop, abstract

I have an abstract class `Foo`:

```js
abstract class Foo {
  constructor() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I don't want classes that extend `Foo` to be able to implement a new constructor:

```js
class Bar {
  constructor() { // Error: can't implement a constructor
    super();
    console.log("hello from Bar's constructor!").
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this with typescript? `private` constructors forbid extension altogether. `protected` constructors allow custom constructors in extending classes.

Comment: `I don't want classes that extend Foo to be able to implement a new constructor:` __Why__?

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea, probably impossible, and also an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is it you really want here?

Comment: If possible, it's just the API I'd like for this. This is not application code, it's for a library.
The developer will provide classes and instances will be automatically constructed for them, which necessitates standardizing the arguments for constructors. It's possible to standardize constructor parameters with interfaces, so I might just opt for that, so custom classes will have to both extend the abstract class and implement the interface.